# WCF 4.0 Instance Management inside of Instanced Service Objects?

Tags: wcf, instance

I have a WCF service using the per-instance call pattern. It is self-hosted, not using IIS at all.
The service class instances another class with the pattern

```
var myfoo = new Foo().GetResultFromDictionary(something);
```

The `Foo` class reads from an embedded resource, does some lookups, and returns an object of `Bar` that the service class then uses.

Creating a new instance for a single call on `Foo()` seems like a waste. Once it loads, all instances of the service should be able to make the call.

Does anyone have design recommendations for this? I do not want to fall into the trap of over-optimizing and pre-optimizing if there is no problem here (eg if .NET Framework will take care of instance management for `Foo`), but I'm not sure.

All ideas appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to work through the System.Runtime.Caching bits, creating a static class that inserts into MemoryCache.Default when the static "constructor" is called, and reading from the cache on all subsequent calls.